# How to call the Last record in an array

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Am I doing this right? I'm trying to call the last element in an array: `$initr`

My IF statements need to specifically ask if each element in the array is the last record. If it turns out true, it will be printing a barcode in that position. (Everything after the IF conditions, you can ignore).

```
<?php
$initr = $this->record;
$last = end($initr); // Put something like this at the top...

// Then something like this for each record. (I don't know if this is correct syntax)...
if     ($initr[4] == $last) {$content=$view->pdf->write1DBarcode('01234567094987654321-'.str_replace("-","",$content), 'IMB', .24, '1.58', '', 0.15, 0.015, $barstyle, '');}
elseif ($initr[5] == $last) {$content=$view->pdf->write1DBarcode('01234567094987654321-'.str_replace("-","",$content), 'IMB', 3, '1.58', '', 0.15, 0.015, $barstyle, '');}
elseif ($initr[6] == $last) {$content=$view->pdf->write1DBarcode('01234567094987654321-'.str_replace("-","",$content), 'IMB', 3, '1.58', '', 0.15, 0.015, $barstyle, '');}
?>
```

Comment: When using `end`, `$last` should contain the last element in the array, so depending on how `$initr` is constructed what you have should be feasible. However, I have no idea how `$initr` is populated to help further.

Comment: Does it work for you or not? Other than *"am I doing this right?"*, I don't see a question

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was valid syntax. It doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to. `$initr` will display the number of barcode records. Say I have 47 labels, the array will display 1-47. (What is weird is I don't even think it starts on 0). If I tell `$initr` to be printed on every record, it will display its number in the array on each.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the last element in an array you can use `end()`.

```
end — Set the internal pointer of an array to its last element
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

Here's an example

```
$myLastElement = end($initr);
```

Comment: I'm more asking if the condition is right: i.e. `($initr[4] == $last)` <-- Does that ask "if 4 is the last record in the array?"